# Obtain <h2> tag related to <li> tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape a website.  I can obtain all the data in the `<li class="level-item">` tag, but I need to obtain the date in the `<h2>` tag related to the corresponding `<li>` tags.

**Desired output:**

```
05182018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/009,sometext,another value,long description 
05182018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/008,sometext,another value,long description 
03092018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/007,sometext,another value,long description 
03092018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/006,sometext,another value,long description 
03092018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/005,sometext,another value,long description 
03092018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/004,sometext,another value,long description
```

**Web page structure:**

```
<h2>May 18, 2018<h2>
<ul>

 <li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/009”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

 <li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/008”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

</ul>

<h2>March 9, 2018<h2>
<ul>
<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/007”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/006”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/005”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/004”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

</ul>

<h2>December 1, 2017<h2>
<ul>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/003”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/002”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>

<li class="level-item"><a href=“/somedirectoryname/anothername/001”><span class=“some text”>another value</span> long description </a></li>
```

**Snippet of my code:**
I only need to obtain the date(s) directly above the `<ul>` tag related to the `<li>` tags.

```
date = results_table.find_all('h2', string=re.compile('January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December'))
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
    changeDateFormat = date.text.strip()
    datePublished = datetime.datetime.strptime(changeDateFormat, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%m%d%Y')
    ul = results_table.find('ul')

    for item in results_table.find_all('li', {'class': 'level-item'}):
        # try to obtain the correct date
        print(ul.previous_element)
        for nextLink in item.find_all('a'):
            for ad_id in nextLink.find_all('span'):
                print(ad_id.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After find all the `<h2>` tags using what you've done, you can get the corresponding `<ul>` tag using [**`find_next()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) or [**`.next_sibling`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling). Then simply iterate over all the `<li>` tags.

**Code:**

```
for date_tag in results_table.find_all('h2'):
    date = date_tag.text
    for item in date_tag.find_next('ul').find_all('li'):
        print(date, item.a['href'], item.span['class'][0], item.get_text(',', strip=True), sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
May 18, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/009,some,another value,long description
May 18, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/008,some,another value,long description
March 9, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/007,some,another value,long description
March 9, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/006,some,another value,long description
March 9, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/005,some,another value,long description
March 9, 2018,/somedirectoryname/anothername/004,some,another value,long description
December 1, 2017,/somedirectoryname/anothername/003,some,another value,long description
December 1, 2017,/somedirectoryname/anothername/002,some,another value,long description
December 1, 2017,/somedirectoryname/anothername/001,some,another value,long description
```

Comment: Note that I've not converted the date into the format you want, since you've already done that. And you can use `find_all('h2', string=re.compile('January|...|December'))` instead of `find_all('h2')` if there are other `<h2>` tags in the HTML.